# Slideshow with owlcarousel2, set movement for each slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, owl-carousel-2

I have created a slide show with owlcarousel2 library, and I would like to set for each slide, a different movement to appear on the screen.

For example now all the slides appears on the screen from right to left, as in a normal slide show. Is possible to set to each slide different appear movement like from left to right for some and from right to left for other?

This is my code:

```
<section class="welcome_area" id="home">
    <div class="welcome_slides">
         <div class="single_slide">
            <div class="slide_text">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table_cell">
                        <center><img src="img/Oregon_Duck_website.gif" /></center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>               
        </div>

        <!-- Slide -->
        <div class="single_slide">
            <div class="slide_text">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table_cell">
                        <center><img src="img/Oregon_Football_1_Black-Gray-Yellow.gif" /></center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>               
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

and js:

```
 if ($.fn.owlCarousel) {
    $(".welcome_slides").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        margin: 0,
        loop: true,
        nav: true,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
        dots: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 7000,
        smartSpeed: 500,
        autoplayHoverPause: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main things you need to do:

1. Include [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) in your page.
2. Create a custom function to select from an array of animation provided from animate.css

   ```
   function getRandomAnimation() {
       var animationList = ['bounce', 'zoomIn', 'flipInX', 'flash', 'pulse', 'rubberBand', 'jello'];
       return animationList[Math.floor(Math.random() * animationList.length)];
   }
   ```

Once you have both things set up you just need to initialize owl carousel and set `animateOut` and `animateIn` to get the random value from `getRandomAnimation()` function.

```
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');

  owl.owlCarousel({
    animateOut: getRandomAnimation,
    animateIn: getRandomAnimation,
    items: 1,
    margin: 30,
    stagePadding: 30,
    smartSpeed: 450,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 2000
  });
```

In the below example I'm creating a random slide animation with autoplay set to 2 seconds just to show you each slide is picking up the different animation.

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');

  //init default carousel
  owl.owlCarousel({
    animateOut: getRandomAnimation,
    animateIn: getRandomAnimation,
    items: 1,
    margin: 30,
    stagePadding: 30,
    smartSpeed: 450,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 2000
  });

 

  function getRandomAnimation() {
    var animationList = ['bounce', 'zoomIn', 'flipInX', 'flash', 'pulse', 'rubberBand', 'jello'];
    return animationList[Math.floor(Math.random() * animationList.length)];
  }

});
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/287321/fff" />
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/1fb84f/fff" />
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/3369cc/fff" />
    <h4>3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/287321/fff" />
    <h4>4</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/9253d6/fff" />
    <h4>5</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/948b46/fff" />
    <h4>6</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/239cba/fff" />
    <h4>7</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/cc43c1/fff" />
    <h4>8</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/7d2477/fff" />
    <h4>9</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/a3541f/fff" />
    <h4>10</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/225911/fff" />
    <h4>11</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/21378f/fff" />
    <h4>12</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And how to set right to left direction or the opposite?

Comment: @StefanoMaglione If you refer back to https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ you can use `slideInLeft` and `slideInRight` to achieve the effect.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is really good. Now the problem is that I should set for every image how it should be shown (left-right or right-left),somenthing like to get the id of the element to understand it

Comment: it should be quite simple, for each of your image add the animation string. eg `<img data-animation="slideInLeft" src="img/Oregon_Duck_website.gif" />`. Then in your `getAnimation()` function just return the string back to owl carousel.

Comment: yes thanks, but I don't know how to get the current item from the callback,from getAnimation for example

Comment: are you using bullets to move around the slide or are you just using the simple prev and next button. The bullets is complicated but doable, it requires a longer process to check which element you are currently clicking and cache the index number, use that index number and point to the right animation. If you are just using prev and next then you can easily target the current slide using something like `return $(.owl-item.active).next().find('img').attr('data-animation')`.

Comment: the function animateIn seems trigger twice every time . . .

Comment: This is because both `animateOut` and `animationIn` are specified and used twice, try comment out `animateOut`.

Comment: the same happens, only with animateIn